# How to mask input field with jQuery mask and Passwordify.js plugin?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-mask

I have an input field where user can enter OTP. I need to make sure that user is able to enter only numbers and it can contain maximum 6 digits. I want to mask the OTP with asterisk.
I know using type as password will mask but in my scenerio I want to mask after some milliseconds not immediately. User can see the entered number for few milliseconds in mobile browser but that's not the case for desktop browser

> <input type="password" />

I found one plugin Passwordify.js which uses jQuery mask library and it's really easy to use and it mask for

> <input type="text" />

https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/mask-password-asterisk-passwordify.html

Now the problem is the value itself becomes ****** but I need to send the actual value eg 878787 as otp to backend.

In addition to that I also have a submit button which is disabled by default and should be enabled only if 6 digits are there in the otp input field.

This is my code

```
    <input type="text" id="otp" name="otp" data-val="" value="" placeholder="Enter OTP" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autofocus>
    <button id="otpsubmit" disabled>Login </button>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#otp").passwordify({
            maxLength: 6,
            numbersOnly: true,
        });
    });
    $("#otp").on('change',function(){
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        if(inputVal.length >= 6) {
            $('#otpsubmit').attr('disabled',false); 
        }else {
            $('#otpsubmit').attr('disabled',true);  
        }   
    });
```

I was wondering if someone have used these libraries for doing something similar , please suggest me how to use it correctly.
I am also open to look for other solution to the masking problem even without using these libraries.

I would like to mention that using these libraries has solved the masking and verify for numeric input scenerio both in mobile and desktop browser, the only problem now is preserving the actual value entered by user instead of ******

I have also tried keydown,keypress and keyup but e.key is always Unidentified and e.keyCode is always 229 in android chrome.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plugin https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask

It has functions to get the masked value. Check your plugin methods as well. There should be a function to retrieve the value.

Comment: I found that the actual value can be pulled from data-val attribute , There is a piece of code inside the plugin but the problem is e.key is unidentified and e.which is always 229 for android chrome browser.
$(this).data('val', $(this).data('val') + e.key);
This code is responsible for updating the data-attribute but only for desktop browser and not for mobile browser